# Magento 2.2 display brand logo product detail page

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, phtml

Please can someone provide step by step instructions or provide tutorial on how to display brand logo on product detail page above the add to cart button.

Thanks

Comment: did you manage to add and save brand logo in admin ?

Comment: yes i have done

Comment: please have a look at https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-shop-by-brand/, this will help you.

Comment: in short you need to set  a phtml on PDP, get brand and based on brand, get brand image.

Comment: Thanks that extension doesnt have feature to show logo on product page I have found another extension that does but it requires manually uploading and setting the logo images which will take many hours as there are thousands of brands - I need a solution where I can upload all logo images to server and then in product view page display - using brand - manufacturer attribute